# Not able to install elementary OS (I think graphics drivers problem)

Tags: system-installation, amd

I am using

> CPU: AMD Ryzen 3 3200G (4) @ 3.600GHz

> GPU: AMD ATI 07:00.0 Picasso

I am writing this using the live mode.
Because that is the only thing I am able to do.

I am trying to dual boot with windows 10

I had recorded the logs for my system using my mobile phone.

[Video link (Didn't copy because it was not possible to that)](https://youtu.be/ds2HG1ZY1Lw)

According to the logs I think the it has something to do with my amdgpu.

I would be grateful if you could help me fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that missing firmware messages is something that you'd need to worry about. I'm running Ryzen 7 4800u without any glitches and with all those messages. Luckily all but one of those firmware files can be downloaded from here https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/amdgpu

and here

https://github.com/Umio-Yasuno/unofficial-amdgpu-firmware-repo/tree/main/amdgpu

and copy to `/lib/firmware/amdgpu`. This will leave only one missing firmware (navi10_something.bin) which I believe belongs to a very old, obsolete, or not yet released product but maybe I'm wrong.

Anyhow, at some point in the video, you have this message `WARN: Installing for i386-pc platform`. To my knowledge elementaryOS does not support i386 architecture.

Hope this helps a bit.